# How can I get a google user object with user id in flutter firebase?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-signin, uid

for the app I am creating I am using google as the sign-in and sign-up option. I need to access some user data in the app. I have the uid, or user id, for the user whose object I want to get. I was wondering if it is possible for me to access a google user object in my app's firebase database with uid, and if so, how?

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

We can not get data from goole using **firebase uid**, You have to store data of google when you are doing signin and signup. You can store current logged in user by `googleSignIn.currentUser.id`. Usually people do the same at **Google SignIn**